# Python email attachments are empty

Tags: python, email, attachment, email-attachments

I'm trying to send an email with attachments using Python 2.7. Everything works except for the attachment contents, which are **0 K** when they arrive attached to the email.

Is something wrong with the encoding?

```
def sendMail(subject, text, *attachmentFilePaths):
    gmailUser = USER
    gmailPassword = PASSWORD
    recipient = RECIPIENT

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = gmailUser
    msg['To'] = recipient
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg.attach(MIMEText(text))

    for attachmentFilePath in attachmentFilePaths:
        msg.attach(getAttachment(attachmentFilePath))

    mailServer = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    mailServer.ehlo()
    mailServer.starttls()
    mailServer.ehlo()
    mailServer.login(gmailUser, gmailPassword)
    mailServer.sendmail(gmailUser, recipient, msg.as_string())
    mailServer.close()

    print('Sent email to %s' % recipient)

def getAttachment(attachmentFilePath):
    contentType, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(attachmentFilePath)

    if contentType is None or encoding is not None:
        contentType = 'application/octet-stream'
    mainType, subType = contentType.split('/', 1)
    file = open(attachmentFilePath, 'rb')

    if mainType == 'text':
        attachment = MIMEText(file.read())
    elif mainType == 'message':
        attachment = email.message_from_file(file)
    elif mainType == 'image':
        attachment = MIMEImage(file.read(),_subType=subType)
    elif mainType == 'audio':
        attachment = MIMEAudio(file.read(),_subType=subType)
    else:
        attachment = MIMEBase(mainType, subType)

    attachment.set_payload(file.read())
    encode_base64(attachment)
    file.close()
    attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment',   filename=os.path.basename(attachmentFilePath))
    return attachment
```

Comment: Test your `getAttachment` function for bugs.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I'm not exactly sure where to start because I'm a novice concerning the email module.

Comment: Find out where the bug is. What function isn't doing what it's supposed to be?

Comment: Why are you setting the encoding to a type? They are two distinct concepts. The type tells what sort of data the MIME part contains; the encoding is a textual representation such as `base64` or `quoted-printable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
if mainType == 'text':
    attachment = MIMEText(file.read())                      # <- read file
elif mainType == 'message':
    attachment = email.message_from_file(file)              # <- read file
elif mainType == 'image':
    attachment = MIMEImage(file.read(),_subType=subType)    # <- read file
elif mainType == 'audio':
    attachment = MIMEAudio(file.read(),_subType=subType)    # <- read file
else:
    attachment = MIMEBase(mainType, subType)

attachment.set_payload(file.read())           # <- re-read file !
```

that means that except in the `else` you'll always replace the payload with an empty string, because the file has already been read.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize you weren't supposed to set the payload each time.